# How to leave body of question empty?

Tags: discussion, bug, questions, asking-questions

What if the whole question is contained in the title? What should I place in the body?

Comment: If the entire question is a single sentence and contained in the question that evidence the question should not even be published before providing more details/explainations/information.  A question body without at least one question, is an instant down vote from me, every single time

Comment: If you can ask a question in the title then you should be able to answer it without using Stack Exchange. SE isn't for trivial questions, and questions with some substance take set-up and a description of the situation.

Answer (score 18):

Place the.... question?

When inside the question page, people read the body of the question, not the title. Well, at least me.

That said, question consisting only of the question without any background, clarification, and things you have tried, will most likely be off topic on most Stack Exchange sites anyway.

You might have better luck with such "questions" on sites like Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: Let's hope Yahoo! Answers doesn't go bankrupt because a lot of answers here on meta would be prone to instant link rot ....

Comment: A lot of Yahoo! answers deserve instant link-rot.